# AMD Hybrid catalyst driver installation for 14.10

Tags: 14.10, catalyst

Is there any worked procedure to install catalyst driver on AMD Hybrid with powerXpress on Utopic? I have tried the procedure explained in wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Ubuntu_Trusty_Installation_Guide modified to `buildpkg Ubuntu/utopic`, with catalyst Omega 14.12. The installation ended smoothly, but `amdconfig --initial -f`, failed to configure the driver. It seems that the problem related to powerXpress issue.

### Many thanks.

Systems: HP 431, with AMD radeon 7000/6400 and Intel HD 3000. Currently opensoure AMD driver is installed from PPA:oibaf/graphics-drivers.

Answer (score 0):

https://askubuntu.com/a/572071/367419 << I have Successfully installed AMD OMEGA Driver by following these steps :

Note: If you previously tried to install any openGL driver "fglrx" purge , autoremove . then reboot your system. follow this